# How can I query users created in $external database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, x509

I'm trying to configure certificate based mongo authentication, generally it works fine but there's one question I cannot find answer for. Suppose I created a user in $external database:

```
use $external
db.createUser({user: "emailAddress=jsmith@example.com,CN=jsmith,OU=Mongo Admins,O=Initech,C=US",
               roles: [{"role" : "root","db" : "admin"}]
})
```

**Q:** How can I query the content of $external database, particularly users data?

Is there any similar way to:

```
use admin
db.system.users.find()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "$external" database isn't a real database, and it contains no data. All users and roles data for all databases is stored in `admin.system.users` or `admin.system.roles`.

The preferred solution is to use the [getUsers command](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.getUsers/).

In the shell, you would issue the following statements:

```
use $external
db.getUsers()
```

If you have the right privileges, you can also query `admin.system.users` to find the users for *any* database, as follows:

```
use admin
db.system.users.find({db: "$external"})
```

Comment: Aha, works! Thanks for help and the link to documentation.